# What hidden nvidia flags should I set to make counter strike 1.6 look better?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I have 100 fps on Counter strike even with 32x anti aliasing. If there are more settings than nvidia control panel shows me, (using nvidia inspector I can see them) that I can use with counter strike 1.6, I would like to use them. I am using opengl mode. Nvidia inspector shows extra options like in the picture.

[image]

Comment: The original Counter Strike? If you've put all the settings on high in the game then the best way to make it look better is to buy Counter Strike: Source. The next best thing to CSS is to buy any game that is [less than eight years old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Source).  Counter strike is ancient and graphics card drivers can't make a game use the latest technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a veteran of CS 1.6 I would say

1. To improve the quality of the picture on the game, open Nvidia control panel go to "3D settings" and select "use my emphasizing" and then move the scroll to "quality".
2. In the CS main menu, click on "option" then "video" then set "color quality" to  "highest 32 bit" then click ok. Also make sure that your resolution is at least 800X600

**Update** CS 1.6 is too old for advanced graphic technologies( like what i see in your Nvidia settings). you can wait Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, it will be released on August 21, 2012. if you do not like to wait,BETA version is available to download.

[image]

Comment: I am already playing in 1920x1080x32 with 100fps 32x anti aliasing 16x anisotropic filterin high quality texture filtering with vsync on.

Comment: @ugurcode then this is the maximum you can run :)